# Is there a way to update the value of a cell in a record based on whether it is in a corresponding column of another table in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three worksheets: players, teams, and weights (how highly a particular attribute is weighted when determining player-team match).

Players

| Name | Age | Height | Free_Throw_Perc | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bod | 23 | 74 | 62 | ... |

Teams
| Team_Name | Age | Height | Free_Throw_Perc | ... |
|-----------|-----|--------|-----------------|-----|
|Team1|23|78|62|...|

Weights
| Team_Name | Age | Height | Free_Throw_Perc | ... |
|:---------:|:---:|:------:|:---------------:|:---:|
| Team1 | 5 | 10 | 10 | ... |

```
CREATE TABLE players (name, age, height, free_throw_perc) AS
SELECT 'Alice', 20, 160, 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Betty', 21, 165, 80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', 22, 170, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra', 23, 175, 60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emily', 24, 180, 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fiona', 25, 185, 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gerri', 26, 190, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Heidi', 27, 195, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Irene', 28, 200, 10 FROM DUAL;
CREATE TABLE teams (team_name, age, height, free_throw_perc) AS
SELECT 'ALPHA', 20,175,90 FROM DUAL;
CREATE TABLE weights team_name, age, height, free_throw_perc) AS
SELECT 'ALPHA', 5,10,10 FROM DUAL;
```

The teams table corresponds to the players table but contains a record for each team detailing their ideal player based on the current composition of the team. The weights table contains a record for each team with an integer value weight stating how much they care about each player attribute. I am trying to compute a total match score for each player-team combination. I was able to do this quite easily with python but am struggling to accomplish the same in SQL.

In Python this would be a simple for loop with logical operators comparing each cell of one dataframe to each cell of another, but the lack of positional referencing in SQL makes this a lot trickier to do and generalize (be able to use the same queries for other pairs of tables with different attributes).

So far I have

```sql
BEGIN 
    FOR c in (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'teams')
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO match_table (players.Name, candidates.c)
        SELECT players.Name, players.c WHERE players.c = teams.c
    END LOOP;

BEGIN 
    FOR c IN (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'weights')
    LOOP
        UPDATE match_table
            SET match_table.c = (SELECT weights.c FROM weights WHERE match_table.c = weights.c)
    END LOOP;
```

From what I can tell that will generate a table of player names with a single column corresponding to a match to a team attribute populated by the corresponding weight and all other columns full of null values. If that is the case, I can group by name to create a singular record with all matches and corresponding weights.

The script should loop through each player and team and compare the attributes of the player with those desired by the team. Where there is a match a new row should be added to the match_table with the player name and nulls values except for the column that matched. That should be done for each player-team attribute match. Then those matches should be replaced by the corresponding weight from the weight table. I would then like to sum those to get a total match score. I can't use the '+' operator because the column nammes will vary. They will always match between the three tables, but there will be varied attributes of interest.

The expected output would look something like:

| players.name | Age | Height | Free_Throw_Perc | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'Alice' | 5 | NULL | NULL | ... |
| 'Alice' | NULL | 10 | NULL | ... |

How would I then sum across each record to find the total match score of each candidate for a team?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your `players`, `teams`, `weights` and `match_table` tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; an explanation (in English, not code) of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data.

Comment: I apologize that I wasn't clearer. The tables are being pulled from databases, so (i think) there would be no create table statements and match_table is just a temporary table to hold the values. I will go back in and edit to try to clear things up and add expected output.

Comment: Of course there are tables in the database and those tables needed a `CREATE TABLE` statement to generate them. We do **NOT** have access to your database so you need to provide us with a way of recreating the database to replicate the problem which is why you need to provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: I will add those in as well. The problem I am trying to figure out how to convey is that there are multiple different player and teams tables with different attributes, which is why I positionally referenced in the python script, but I will put an example in the question. Thank you for your help. As you can probably tell I'm pretty far out of my comfort zone.

Comment: The tables you copied and edited from my answer have no concept of which player belongs to which team so you cannot correlate the weights for any particular team to the corresponding players.

Comment: The players are unassigned. The point is to see how well they would match with a team. Trying to basically score potential candidates based on potential. I'm sorry if I am not making sense.

Comment: Note that "worksheet" and "cell" are concepts from spreadsheets, not relational databases, and "looping" is more used in programming. Applying the wrong concepts will prevent you from solving problems and lead to mistakes. Learn the relational model and at least a little about the relational calculi and relational algebra. Codd's seminal "[A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks](https://web.archive.org/web/20070612235326/http://www.acm.org/classics/nov95/toc.html)" is short, not too difficult and carries a wealth of information.

Comment: In particular, a central concept to solve this problem is that of [joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Joins_and_join-like_operators).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE teams ( id, name ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alpha' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beta'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Gamma' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE players (name, team, age, height, free_throw_perc) AS
SELECT 'Alice', 1, 20, 160, 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Betty', 1, 21, 165, 80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', 1, 22, 170, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra', 2, 23, 175, 60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emily', 2, 24, 180, 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fiona', 2, 25, 185, 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gerri', 3, 26, 190, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Heidi', 3, 27, 195, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Irene', 3, 28, 200, 10 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE weights(team, key, weight) AS
SELECT 1, 'AGE',             1.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'HEIGHT',          0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'FREE_THROW_PERC', 0.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'AGE',             0.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'HEIGHT',          1.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'FREE_THROW_PERC', 0.8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'AGE',             0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'HEIGHT',          0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'FREE_THROW_PERC', 1.0 FROM DUAL;
```

And you want to insert the sum of the `weight` column from the `weights` table multiplied by the respective value in the `players` table into the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE match_table(
  team  INT,
  value NUMBER
);
```

Then you can use the following `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO match_table (team, value)
SELECT p.team,
       SUM(p.value * w.weight)
FROM   ( SELECT name, team, key, value
         FROM   players
         UNPIVOT ( value FOR key IN (age, height, free_throw_perc) )
       ) p
       INNER JOIN weights w
       ON ( p.team = w.team AND p.key = w.key )
GROUP BY p.team
```

Then the table will contain the weighted totals:

| TEAM | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 660 |
| 3 | 393 |
| 1 | 358.5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JJtSMdmE)

---

And if your `match_table` is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE match_table(
  player          VARCHAR2(20),
  team            INT,
  age             NUMBER,
  height          NUMBER,
  free_throw_perc NUMBER,
  total           NUMBER
);
```

Then you can use the query (and calculate the total with the `+` operator):

```sql
INSERT INTO match_table (player, team, age, height, free_throw_perc, total)
SELECT p.name,
       p.team,
       p.age * w.age_weight,
       p.height * w.height_weight,
       p.free_throw_perc * w.free_throw_perc_weight,
       p.age * w.age_weight
       + p.height * w.height_weight
       + p.free_throw_perc * w.free_throw_perc_weight
FROM   players p
       INNER JOIN ( 
         SELECT *
         FROM   weights
         PIVOT  (
           MAX(weight)
           FOR key IN (
             'AGE' AS age_weight,
             'HEIGHT' AS height_weight,
             'FREE_THROW_PERC' AS free_throw_perc_weight
           )
         )
       ) w
       ON (p.team = w.team)
```

Which gives the values:

| PLAYER | TEAM | AGE | HEIGHT | FREE_THROW_PERC | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 1 | 20 | 80 | 18 | 118 |
| Betty | 1 | 21 | 82.5 | 16 | 119.5 |
| Carol | 1 | 22 | 85 | 14 | 121 |
| Debra | 2 | 0 | 175 | 48 | 223 |
| Emily | 2 | 0 | 180 | 40 | 220 |
| Fiona | 2 | 0 | 185 | 32 | 217 |
| Gerri | 3 | 13 | 95 | 30 | 138 |
| Heidi | 3 | 13.5 | 97.5 | 20 | 131 |
| Irene | 3 | 14 | 100 | 10 | 124 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/94EOHy7X)

---

Or, if the players are uncorrelated to a team then:

```sql
INSERT INTO match_table (player, team, age, height, free_throw_perc, total)
SELECT p.name,
       w.team,
       p.age * w.age_weight,
       p.height * w.height_weight,
       p.free_throw_perc * w.free_throw_perc_weight,
       p.age * w.age_weight
       + p.height * w.height_weight
       + p.free_throw_perc * w.free_throw_perc_weight
FROM   players p
       CROSS JOIN ( 
         SELECT *
         FROM   weights
         PIVOT  (
           MAX(weight)
           FOR key IN (
             'AGE' AS age_weight,
             'HEIGHT' AS height_weight,
             'FREE_THROW_PERC' AS free_throw_perc_weight
           )
         )
       ) w
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| PLAYER | TEAM | AGE | HEIGHT | FREE_THROW_PERC | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 1 | 20 | 80 | 18 | 118 |
| Alice | 2 | 0 | 160 | 72 | 232 |
| Alice | 3 | 10 | 80 | 90 | 180 |
| Betty | 1 | 21 | 82.5 | 16 | 119.5 |
| Betty | 2 | 0 | 165 | 64 | 229 |
| Betty | 3 | 10.5 | 82.5 | 80 | 173 |
| Carol | 1 | 22 | 85 | 14 | 121 |
| Carol | 2 | 0 | 170 | 56 | 226 |
| Carol | 3 | 11 | 85 | 70 | 166 |
| Debra | 1 | 23 | 87.5 | 12 | 122.5 |
| Debra | 2 | 0 | 175 | 48 | 223 |
| Debra | 3 | 11.5 | 87.5 | 60 | 159 |
| Emily | 1 | 24 | 90 | 10 | 124 |
| Emily | 2 | 0 | 180 | 40 | 220 |
| Emily | 3 | 12 | 90 | 50 | 152 |
| Fiona | 1 | 25 | 92.5 | 8 | 125.5 |
| Fiona | 2 | 0 | 185 | 32 | 217 |
| Fiona | 3 | 12.5 | 92.5 | 40 | 145 |
| Gerri | 1 | 26 | 95 | 6 | 127 |
| Gerri | 2 | 0 | 190 | 24 | 214 |
| Gerri | 3 | 13 | 95 | 30 | 138 |
| Heidi | 1 | 27 | 97.5 | 4 | 128.5 |
| Heidi | 2 | 0 | 195 | 16 | 211 |
| Heidi | 3 | 13.5 | 97.5 | 20 | 131 |
| Irene | 1 | 28 | 100 | 2 | 130 |
| Irene | 2 | 0 | 200 | 8 | 208 |
| Irene | 3 | 14 | 100 | 10 | 124 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i2Dv8wLS)

Comment: Would there be a way to do this so that the weight is only applied if the player attribute matches the team attribute: if p.age = t.age then add weight to player record in match_table? Also would it be possible to generalize it to apply regardless of column label.  I'm sure I just didn't explain it clearly enough, but the column names vary. The goal is to be able to run this no matter the column labels.

Comment: @guperator The team weighting and player value are already correlated based on the attribute type so I do not understand what more you want.

Comment: I fat fingered the enter key and edited the comment with an example of what I mean.

Comment: @guperator In SQL (not just Oracle) you must have a known columns (both in number and in name) in the output; so it is impossible to generalise it to apply to arbitrary labels with a static SQL statement as those labels must be known beforehand, If you want to have a dynamic output then you will need to dynamically generate the query. As for your other question, if you have different requirements then you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a well-defined set of requirements (rather than broadening an existing question, even with a poorly defined scope).

Comment: Those were the requirements I was trying to convey originally. I'm sorry that didn't come across, but I did say "The script should loop through each player and team and compare the attributes of the player with those desired by the team. Where there is a match a new row should be added to the match_table with the player name and nulls values except for the column that matched. That should be done for each player-team attribute match. Then those matches should be replaced by the corresponding weight from the weight table." Thank you for your help.